# Not executing while running the java program in geany

Tags: java, ubuntu, geany

I don't think there are any problems in my java code since I ran the program properly in BluJ, but I use geany extensively instead. However, a strange problem occurred today while building the program in geany. I have defined the main method properly in my code, but despite my program got compiled without any errors, while running it after executing the program in geany I got this error:

> **Error: Main method not found in class Ter, please define the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
>   application class must extend javafx.application.Application**

My program is:

```
public class Ter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int scored=3;
        int concede=5;
        char result = (scored > concede) ? 'W':'L';
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: and the package of that class is?

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to java programming, hence I don't know much about it , I mean which package of that class ?

Comment: Every Java .class file must start with a line `package ...` denoting the package the class is in. The package is also reflected by the path, so if your file is in the package `com.acme.project`, it will be in the folder "com/acme/project/".  
If in doubt you can create a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the entire code.